# How can one set selected options for a cake php FormHelper multiple select?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

The template Form element would be:

```
$ingredientOptions = array('Potato','Peanut','Parsley');
echo $this->Form->input('FavouriteIngredients', array('multiple' => true, 'options' => $ingredientOptions);
echo $this->Form->input('AllergicIngredients', array('multiple' => true, 'options' => $ingredientOptions);
```

This creates two (ugly) multiple select boxes, each with a list consisting of elements from the options array, none of which are selected.

To set initial values, I've tried a few things in the controller without success:

```
$this->set('FavouriteIngredients',array(1,2));
$this->request->data['FavouriteIngredients'] = array(1,2);
```

These multiple selects are for two HABTM relationships defined in the Customer model:

```
class Customer extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'FavouriteIngredients' => 
             array(
                'className' => 'Ingredient',
                'joinTable' => 'customer_ingredients_favourite'
            );

        'AllergicIngredients' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Ingredient',
                'joinTable' => 'customer_ingredients_allergic'
            );

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem in production was that the values didn't exist in the options array. So this works:

```
$this->request->data['Customer']['FavouriteIngredients'] = array(1,2);
```